# Rails 3 console raising errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, console

I'm upgrading a Rails 2.3.8 app to Rails 3.0.17 and using RVM (Ruby 1.9.3) in a mac osx Lion environment. (already using bundler).

My app is working OK, but the rails console is giving me errors: (on any DB call)

```
User.first
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
    from /Users/franklin/rails_apps/myapp/app/models/user.rb:84:in `<class:User>'
    from /Users/franklin/rails_apps/myapp/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:458:in `load'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:458:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load_file'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:344:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/franklin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help.

Comment: Stack trace clearly says that you have problem on line 84 in user.rb

Comment: It's happening only in a few models calls.

Comment: Thanks UncleGene. I was just blind by the hassle this upgrade is being for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting Paperclip configs on the user model, everything worked fine. Thanks for the advise.